# profileinstaller is crashing my android app (but I'm not using it)

Tags: android, kotlin

in an Android app (a standard android app, written in Kotlin), I'm getting the following crash.  Note: none of my code is in the stacktrace, and I haven't included profileinstaller as a dependency, I'm not working with it in any shape or form.

```
                 E  java.lang.RuntimeException: AssetManager has been closed
                 E      at android.content.res.AssetManager.ensureOpenLocked(AssetManager.java:519)
                 E      at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:897)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.DeviceProfileWriter.openStreamFromAssets(DeviceProfileWriter.java:190)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.DeviceProfileWriter.getProfileInputStream(DeviceProfileWriter.java:210)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.DeviceProfileWriter.read(DeviceProfileWriter.java:164)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstaller.transcodeAndWrite(ProfileInstaller.java:444)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstaller.writeProfile(ProfileInstaller.java:575)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstaller.writeProfile(ProfileInstaller.java:515)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstaller.writeProfile(ProfileInstaller.java:479)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer.lambda$writeInBackground$2(ProfileInstallerInitializer.java:145)
                 E      at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:2)
                 E      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                 E      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                 E      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I see its been pulled in by androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime, androidx.activity:activity, androidx.navigation:navigation-common, and others.  I didn't ask for it, I don't want it, how to do I get rid it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. The app uses the assetManager just once.

```
context.resources.assets.use { am ->
     // code that use the assetManager
}
```

the use clause auto closes the assetManager.   We didn't open it, we shouldn't close it.

I suppose that begs the question of why we are given the option to close it.